# The System Variable "MESSAGE_TEXT" is not working with SIGNAL statement in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My code is:i am using mysql 5.6 and workbench 6.3CE

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`windows7test-pc` PROCEDURE `p`(divisor INT)
 BEGIN
 Declare MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(200);
 IF divisor = 0 THEN
 BEGIN
  DECLARE my_error CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
  SIGNAL my_error;
  set MESSAGE_TEXT='error occured in if block';
 END;
 END IF;

 END
```

when i apply this stored procedure then i get no error but when i run this by calling **call p(0)** statement then i get only system error message which is **Error Code: 1644
 Unhandled user-defined exception condition**.but my question is that why the mysql server not generate my error message whic is **MESSAGE_TEXT='error occured in if block';** ?

Comment: you haven't declare this variable. That is the problem

Comment: @Dinidu:-thanks,now i declaring MESSAGE_TEXT Variable.But  why the value of this  variable not appear with error

Answer (score 3):

You do not declare `message_text` as a variable.

You do not `DECLARE ... CONDITION`.

You do have to include the values to `SET` in the same statement as `SIGNAL`.

The syntax is simply this:

```
IF divisor = 0 THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'division: ur doing it wrong';
END IF;
```

Comment: When I ran into this issue I didn't realize there shouldn't be a semi-colon after SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'