# The System Variable "MESSAGE_TEXT" is not working with SIGNAL statement in Mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My code is:i am using mysql 5.6 and workbench 6.3CE

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`windows7test-pc` PROCEDURE `p`(divisor INT)
 BEGIN
 Declare MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(200);
 IF divisor = 0 THEN
 BEGIN
  DECLARE my_error CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
  SIGNAL my_error;
  set MESSAGE_TEXT='error occured in if block';
 END;
 END IF;

 END
```

when i apply this stored procedure then i get no error but when i run this by calling **call p(0)** statement then i get only system error message which is **Error Code: 1644
 Unhandled user-defined exception condition**.but my question is that why the mysql server not generate my error message whic is **MESSAGE_TEXT='error occured in if block';** ?

Comment: Posting essentially [the same question twice, three hours apart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584573/the-system-variable-message-text-is-not-working-with-signal-statement-in-mysql) is not productive.  Your code is not working because it is not written correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SIGNAL SQLSTATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `p`(divisor INT)
 BEGIN
 Declare MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(200);
 IF divisor = 0 THEN
   BEGIN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
     set MESSAGE_TEXT='error occured in if block';
   END;
 END IF;
 END

CALL `p`(0)
-- error occured in if block
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33d6e5/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @lad2015:-thanks this code works fine.but i want to know what is wrong in  my code?

Comment: Based on quick look at doc I would say that  45000 is generic  error message and I you want custom message you may use  [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5a03/2/0)